# JInstaller: :Install: Can't find XML setup file

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla! 3.8.10 Stable [ Amani ] 26-June-2018 15:45 GMT is the version i installed but am getting an error when installing template, saying:

> JInstaller: :Install: Can't find XML setup file

The Compatibility of the template is: Joomla 3.4.4+

How can I fix that?

Comment: check the zip, are you able to find .xml file in it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your template is .zip file and contain only template files? Some templates could be provided within zipped folder.